# Java persistent socket conexión?

Tags: java, socket

Bueno, estoy iniciándome en los sockets en java.
Y la verdad estoy un poco confuso. Estado realizando ejemplos bastantes sencillos de conexión, donde el server se pone a la escucha y puede recibir multiples clientes (con threads).

Ahora quería avanzar un poco mas en el tema, y mantener una comunicación constante por ambos casos.
Estado leyendo algo de asynchronous socket, pero no sé si es la única manera de hacerlo.
Básicamente lo que trato de hacer es lo siguiente:

- Server escucha ....
- Cliente conecta, envia msg...
- Server recibe msg ...
- Cliente mantiene el socket ...
- Server pregunta a cliente si sigue vivo ...(sigue vivo)
- Server envia msg ...
- Cliente recibe msg ...
- Server sigue a la escucha ... Cliente desconecta ...
- Server indica que cliente X ha desconectado ...

(También quería añadir que sí el servidor desconecta, indicar al cliente, que lo intente cada X minutos la conexion)

Class Server

```
    public class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ServerSocket ss;
            System.out.print("Inicializando servidor... ");
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(10578);
                System.out.println("\t[OK]");
                int idSession = 0;
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket;
                    socket = ss.accept();
                    System.out.println("Nueva conexión entrante: " + socket);
                    ((ServidorHilo) new ServidorHilo(socket, idSession)).start();
                    idSession++;
                }


 } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Class servidorhilo

```
public class ServidorHilo extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private int idSessio;
    public ServidorHilo(Socket socket, int id) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.idSessio = id;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServidorHilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void desconnectar() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServidorHilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String accion = "";
        try {
            accion = dis.readUTF();
            if(accion.equals("hola")){
                System.out.println("El cliente con idSesion "+this.idSessio+" saluda");
                dos.writeUTF("adios");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServidorHilo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        desconnectar();
    }
}
```

Class cliente

```
class Persona extends Thread {

    protected Socket sk;
    protected DataOutputStream dos;
    protected DataInputStream dis;
    private int id;

    public Persona(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sk = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10578);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(id + " envía saludo");
            dos.writeUTF("hola");
            String respuesta = "";
            respuesta = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(id + " Servidor devuelve saludo: " + respuesta);
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
            sk.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Persona.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList< Thread> clients = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            clients.add(new Persona(i));
        }
        for (Thread thread : clients) {
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Por lo que veis en el código, tengo multiples conexiones al servidor con threads, pero a la hora de realizar una conexión persistente, no sé por donde coger el todo por los cuernos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tus conexiones sean asíncronas, lo que necesitas es manejar DOS hilos por conexión: uno para escritura y otro de lectura. En tu conexión de server tienes el hilo de lectura, pero te falta el de escritura. Para el de escritura es recomendable manejar una cola de mensajes de salida, a la cual se agreguen los mensajes salientes, y el hilo de escritura va tomando mensajes de dicha cola y los escribe al OutputStream.

Del lado de lectura ya lo tienes, simplemente lees y procesas las peticiones. Sólo que es preferente que los mensajes entrantes los pongas en una cola de lectura para que otros hilos puedan procesar esos mensajes (ya sea en un thread pool o lo que sea) y que tu hilo de lectura se dedique única y exclusivamente a *leer* mensajes de entrada, porque si procesas los mensajes ahí mismo, el buffer del socket se puede llenar y pierdes mensajes.

Y del lado del cliente tienes que hacer básicamente lo mismo: dos hilos por conexión, uno para escritura y uno para lectura, con sus respectivas colas. Y entonces lo único que te falta es que pongas en uno de los dos lados, un timer para que se envíe un mensaje de eco para mantener la conexión viva en periodos de inactividad.

Te recomiendo que en vez de hacer esto a mano, utilices alguna biblioteca como Netty, que te simplifica las cosas y haces una programación más orientada a eventos. Al principio puede parecerte un poco más complicado, pero te quedará algo mucho más robusto de lo que puedes hacer a mano, y con menos código.